# Change Title Bar on a Tk window

Tags: python, tkinter, titlebar

Im trying to make the top bar of my Tk window say calculator instaed of Tk is there anyway to do that also can i change the little icon beside it to a differnt image if not the title would just be fine Thank you

Here is the code:

```
import math

def calculate():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        num2 = float(enter2.get())
        result = num1 * num2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!')
def calculate2():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        num2 = float(enter2.get())
        result = num1 / num2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!')
def calculate3():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        num2 = float(enter2.get())
        result = num1 + num2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!')
def calculate4():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        num2 = float(enter2.get())
        result = num1 - num2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!',fg="white")
def calculate5():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        result = num1**2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!',fg="white")
def calculate6():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        result = math.sqrt(num1)
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!',fg="white")



root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')



label1 = Label(root, text='First Number:',bg="black", fg="white")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=2)
enter1 = Entry(root, bg='white')
enter1.grid(row=1, column=0,columnspan=2)


label2 = Label(root, text='Second Number:',bg="black", fg="white")
label2.grid(row=2, column=0,columnspan=2)
enter2 = Entry(root, bg='white')
enter2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)



btn1 = Button(root, text='-Multiply-', command=calculate,               bg="black",activebackground="green", fg="white")
btn1.grid(row=4, column=0)
btn2 = Button(root, text='-Divide-', command=calculate2,     bg="black",activebackground="orange", fg="white")
btn2.grid(row=5, column=0)
btn3 = Button(root, text='-Add-', command=calculate3,  bg="black",activebackground="purple", fg="white")
btn3.grid(row=5, column=1)
btn4 = Button(root, text='-Subtract-', command=calculate4,  bg="black",activebackground="red", fg="white")
btn4.grid(row=4, column=1)
btn5 = Button(root, text='Square (Only First #)', command=calculate5,    bg="black",activebackground="cyan", fg="white")
btn5.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)
btn6 = Button(root, text='Square Root (only First #)', command=calculate6,  bg="black",activebackground="yellow", fg="white")
btn6.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2,)
label3 = Label(root, bg="black")
label3.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)


enter1.focus()

enter1.bind('<Return>', func=lambda e:enter2.focus_set())

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
root.title("My Application Title")
```

The method for changing the icon can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11180300/1142167).