# How do I add back the icon to the task bar in guizero/tkinter python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, windows-10, icons, guizero

I am trying to add back the icon for a custom app window with the border removed. I made this in Guizero/Tkinter. I Need to be able to add back the icon so it can be displayed in the taskbar. The icon need to be displayed as active so that you can hide/minimize into the task bar and show/reopen the window from there. I have tried "root.iconify()".

```
from guizero import *

app=App(title='Test',bg='#121212',width=750,height=550)
root = app.tk
#Icon does not display when overrideredirect is True
app.tk.iconbitmap("icon.ico")


#Remove window border
root.overrideredirect(True)
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910858/how-to-specify-where-a-tkinter-window-opens
#base on answer given byRachel Gallen
def center_window(width=750, height=500):
    # get screen width and height
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    # calculate position x and y coordinates
    x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))


#menu bar
Top_box = Box(app,height=35,width='fill', align="top")
Top_box.bg='white'

#window title
left_box = Box(Top_box,height=35,width='fill', align="left")
left_box.bg='#121212'
text = Text(left_box, text=" Test Project",align="left")
text.text_color='gray'
text.tk.padx=15
text.tk.config(font='Helvetica 15 bold')

#end of window title


#Exit/quit button
Quit_button = PushButton(Top_box, text="X", command=quit ,align='right')
Quit_button.bd=0
Quit_button.text_size=22
Quit_button.text_color='purple'
Quit_button.bg='gray'
Quit_button.tk.config(activebackground='black',highlightthickness=10,bd=0,highlightbackground='red')


#Minmize/hide button
Minmize_button = PushButton(Top_box, text="-", command=app.hide ,align='right')
Minmize_button.tk.config(activebackground='green',highlightthickness=2,bd=0,highlightbackground='red',font=("Verdana", 31))
Minmize_button.text_color="purple"


#Content of the window
Canvas_box = Box(app,height='fill',width='fill', align="top")
Canvas_box.bg='green'
Text=Text(Canvas_box,text='Test',align='top',size=26)
Text.text_color='white'

center_window(750, 500)

app.display()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not perfect this is pretty close. It adds the icon back when you minimize the window. It's a complete custom window with drag support.
I integrated and update some code made by others to work with Guizero 1.2.0.

```
from guizero import *
app = App(bg='white',title='Test',width=645,height=275)
#Removes window border and title bar
app.tk.overrideredirect(True)
#app.icon="Shorcut_Icon1.ico"

#minimize system to re-add icon 
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714026/python-tkinter-restore-window-without-title-bar
#base on Answer given by Mike - SMT
def close():
    app.destroy()

def minimizeWindow():
    app.hide()
    app.tk.overrideredirect(False)
    app.tk.iconify()

def check_map(event): # apply override on deiconify.
    if str(event) == "<Map event>":
        app.tk.overrideredirect(1)
        print ('Deiconified', event)
    else:
        print ('Iconified', event)


winControl_container=Box(app,width=app.width,height=35,align='top')
Bottom_line=Box(winControl_container,width=app.width,height=1,align='bottom')
Bottom_line.bg='blue'
closeButton= PushButton(winControl_container, text='X', command=close,align='right')
minButton= PushButton(winControl_container, text='—', command=minimizeWindow,align='right')


#Start of window movement system
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055267/tkinter-mouse-drag-a-window-without-borders-eg-overridedirect1
#base on answer given by David58
lastClickX = 0
lastClickY = 0


def SaveLastClickPos(event):
    global lastClickX, lastClickY
    lastClickX = event.x
    lastClickY = event.y


def Dragging(event):
    x, y = event.x - lastClickX + app.tk.winfo_x(), event.y - lastClickY + app.tk.winfo_y()
    app.tk.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x , y))
    
    

    
#Adds window movement/dragging events. Just comment this out if you don't want the window to be able to move.
app.when_left_button_pressed=SaveLastClickPos
app.when_mouse_dragged=Dragging
#End of movement/drag system


app.tk.bind('<Map>', check_map) # added bindings to pass windows status to function
app.tk.bind('<Unmap>', check_map)

#Center window system
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910858/how-to-specify-where-a-tkinter-window-opens
#base on answer given byRachel Gallen

def center_window(width, height):
    # get screen width and height
    screen_width = app.tk.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = app.tk.winfo_screenheight()

    # calculate position x and y coordinates
    x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
    app.tk.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))

center_window(app.width,app.height)



app.display()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# This works fine do not adjust code
# works with version 1.1.0
# This is no longer supposed to work with the latest version of guizero.
#
# I have tried with version 1.3.0 which is the 
# latest version on 05/01/22
# and it still appears to work without any changes needed
# in comments below.

# You will need to use the command below instead.
# WindowsName.tk.iconbitmap("Icon.ico")
# Imports ---------------
from tkinter import *
from guizero import App

root = Tk()

app = App(title="App window")
root.iconbitmap(app, 'green-finger.ico')
# Root window is shown when the program is run, 
# so it must be destroyed it to stop this happening.
root.destroy()
app.display()
```