# Python 3.4 Tkinter Claims Image Doesn't Exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am just learning the basics of tkinter with usingpython.com/using-tkinter. However, when I try to change the icon of the window that shows up, with an icon 'TKUsage.ico' saved in my desktop, I get the following error: `TclError: bitmap "TKUsage.ico" not defined`. I have ensured that the directories are the same, and I have even tried using the full file path, but it still claims the image doesn't exist. My full code is here:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.wm_iconbitmap('TKUsage.ico')
lbl1 = tkinter.Label(window, text='Username:')
ent1 = tkinter.Entry(window)
lbl2 = tkinter.Label(window, text='Password:')
ent2 = tkinter.Entry(window)
btn = tkinter.Button(window, text='Button')
lbl1.pack()
ent1.pack()
lbl2.pack()
ent2.pack()
btn.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Could someone tell me how to make sure it finds the image?

Comment: Are you  using `~` in the path?

Comment: Ah ok, your problem is it is a .ico and you are using linux

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16161574/2141635

Comment: Save it as an xbm then use `@/full/path/to/file.xbm`

Comment: Nope you would have to concat to the start of what expanduser returned ,just type the full path

Comment: Where you have been typing it all the time, bitmap=@/....., if you look at the answer I linked to it shows you all this

Comment: It's still returning `TclError: error reading bitmap file "~/Desktop/TKUsage.xbm"` even though I'm using the full path without the tilde.

Comment: You are still not passing the full path, I can also see a tilde so you are definitely passing it

Comment: I'm not using the tilde in the typing, I'm just using that so I can type it faster. The code is window.wm_iconbitmap(bitmap='@/home/aaryankainth/Desktop.xbm')

Comment: Lots of comments here. It would be wise to remove any comments that have become obsolete and update the question to the current standing, i.e., what information has been provided that (such as you're on Linux), what has been tried so far and what the standing problem is.

Comment: @/home/username/Desktop/filename is a full path

Comment: That's what I'm using though.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the file, actually. When I try to open it in ubuntu, it says it's an invalid xbm file.

Comment: I don't think I understand this. It's ok, I'll try to solve it later. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: If the file is corrupt you will have to find another way to create it. I tested the solution myself and it works

Comment: I managed to make it work, but I need to crop it, and I don't know how to on ubuntu. Dang it!