# image "pyimage" doesn't exist

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I've seen a couple questions with the same error reported in them. Yet none of them seem to solve the problem.

When I run my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

screen = Canvas(master, width = 200, height = 200)
screen.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

ammo = PhotoImage(file='ammo.gif')
screen.create_image(80,40 , image=ammo)

master.mainloop()
```

When i run it it gives me the error **'image "pyimage#" doesn't exist'**
(The # changes every time. Increasing by one each time you run the program)

When I put in the file path directly the image displays. But it cant seem to find the image when i have it in my Directory.

Help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274072/tkinter-pyimage-doesnt-exist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602594/how-do-i-fix-the-image-pyimage10-doesnt-exist-error-and-why-does-it-happen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251161/tkinter-tclerror-image-pyimage3-doesnt-exist

Comment: none of those solved the problem for me

Comment: For me the code runds without error, if I have an `ammo.gif` file next to the Python file.

Comment: If the absolute path is helping, you can use `import os` and create a fill file path with `filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'ammo.gif')`

Comment: I think this could be a namespace problem, try doing `import tkinter as tk` and then starting all of your tkinter declarations with `tk.`