# How do I change the task bar and desktop icon of a program in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, desktop, taskbar, .ico

I am working on a game in Python 3.5.2 and Tkinter.
I am wondering how to change the icon that appears in the taskbar when you open the application and that appears on the desktop when you create a shortcut to the program.

I have already converted the file that I would like to use to a .ICO file, but it is also available as a .PNG and .GIF.

I will be using cx_Freeze to create the .exe executable. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You'd likely need to create an EXE

Comment: What are you using to create the .exe file?

Comment: I am using cx_Freeze to create the .exe.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176638/python-setting-application-icon) can help you.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question. Have yet to try it out though.