# `tkinter.iconbitmap` method returns empty string

Tags: python, unit-testing, tkinter

I have an app:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Set app title
        self.app_title = 'Visual Python'
        self.title(self.app_title)
        # Set app icon
        self.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
```

And a test:

```
class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = App()

    def test_app_title(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.app.title(), 'Visual Python')

    def test_app_icon(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.app.iconbitmap(), 'icon.ico')
```

When I ran the test with `py -3 -m unittest`, I get this output:

```
F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_app_icon (test.test_app.TestApp)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ismailarilik\visual-python\test\test_app.py", line 12, in 
test_app_icon
    self.assertEqual(self.app.iconbitmap(), 'icon.ico')
AssertionError: '' != 'icon.ico'
+ icon.ico

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.279s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Why does `iconbitmap` method here return an empty string instead of the given `'icon.ico'` string?

Answer (score 1):

[*Source*](https://wiki.tcl.tk/3177):

> If an empty string is specified for bitmap, then any current icon
>   bitmap is cancelled for window. If bitmap is specified then the
>   command returns an empty string. Otherwise it returns the name of the
>   current icon bitmap associated with window, **or an empty string if
>   window has no icon bitmap**.

I think your situation falls into the last case highlighted in bold text. I mean you have to be sure the icon is set [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176638/tkinter-tclerror-error-reading-bitmap-file), depending on your platform.

Comment: I use Windows and can see the icon on the left of title. Does it mean that the icon was set correctly?

Comment: If you see the icon visually on the GUI, then sure it is set correctly. I can not reproduce your issue on my Linux machine though (better to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because I think some more investigation should be performed on your code to see where is the issue)

Comment: I used this icon in my app: https://www.python.org/static/favicon.ico I think you can reproduce the issue with this info. But as I read discussions, Tkinter doesn't support _.ico_ images on GNU/Linux environments.

Comment: I see the same on Windows 7, Python 3.6.5. The icon is set correctly but `iconbitmap()` returns an empty string.