# .ico file not defined when setting window icon icon tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When i tried to change the tkinter icon with my favicon it threw an error.

code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

The following error is shown:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2080, in wm_iconbitmap
  return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
  _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "favicon.ico" not defined
```

- The icon is in the same path as the .py file.
- Tried copying path of file and pasting.
- checked problem in many websites.

Comment: maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176638/tkinter-tclerror-error-reading-bitmap-file) would help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter TclError: error reading bitmap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176638/tkinter-tclerror-error-reading-bitmap-file)