# Tkinter Create Line with Stipple

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I found the possibility to make a stippled line in Python tkinter. (Seen here: [Canvas Line Objects](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_line.html))

It states that I need a bitmap file and define `stipple=bitmap_file`

I tried this in:

```
# Import the required libraries
from tkinter import *

# Create an instance of tkinter frame or window
win=Tk()

# Set the size of the tkinter window
win.geometry("700x350")

# Create a canvas widget
canvas=Canvas(win, width=500, height=300)
canvas.pack()

# Add a line in canvas widget
canvas.create_line(100,200,200,35, stipple='@CheckedLine.bmp', fill='red', width=5)

win.mainloop()
```

However, the console then says:
`_tkinter.TclError: error reading bitmap file "CheckedLine.bmp"`

Can someone help?

Comment: The document says it is XBM image, not BMP.

Comment: @acw1668 A recommended program on Windows, where I can create xbm then? Paint just does .bmp

Comment: I use paint program to create the BMP image and then use `ImageMagick` command line tool to convert BMP to XBM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_line.html) linked to in the OP, also links to [a detailed description](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/bitmaps.html) of what they meant by a "bitmap", they never mention it to be a file but rather a bitmap.

> stipple
>
> To draw a stippled line, set this option to a bitmap that specifies
> the stippling pattern, such as stipple='gray25'. See Section 5.7,
> “Bitmaps” for the possible values.

Section 5.7 details about the files to be used -:

> The graphic above shows Button widgets bearing the standard bitmaps.
> From left to right, they are 'error', 'gray75', 'gray50', 'gray25',
> 'gray12', 'hourglass', 'info', 'questhead', 'question', and 'warning'.
>
> You can use your own bitmaps. Any file in .xbm (X bit map) format will
> work. In place of a standard bitmap name, use the string '@' followed
> by the pathname of the .xbm file.

---

For more information on the .xbm format [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_BitMap) may be useful.

> Some image viewers/converters, e.g., [XnView](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XnView), [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) and [IrfanView](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IrfanView),
> support XBM. A 48×48 XBM can be converted to Ikon and eventually
> [X-Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Face) with [Netpbm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm) tools.
>
> ImageMagick supports converting images both to and from XBM. GIMP
> may be used to create or modify images using the XBM format, and also
> supports converting images to and from the XBM format.

---

**NOTE:**

Incase, you use the standard bitmaps as listed above and in the link provided, they render to look like this -:

[image: STANDARD BITMAPS]

Comment: I converted the .bmp to .xbm via GIMP. But the same error message occurs.

Comment: @Soda did you change the filename in your code?

Comment: Change the extension of the file to .xbm in the code as well.

Comment: Yes of course. ```canvas.create_line(100,200,200,35, stipple='@CheckedLine.xbm', fill='darkred', width=5)```

Comment: can you provide a link to that xbm file of somewhere from where i can download it, it might help me test out a few things i think might work out

Comment: You can download the file here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/npdztbktcxeioyv/CheckedLine.xbm/file

Comment: @Soda it might be related with the size of your stipple texture as well, like the size in pixels.. I found [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176638/tkinter-tclerror-error-reading-bitmap-file) which might help fixing the file, as the code seems to be exactly as intended.